# How do I pass variable length arguments to parameters of another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing

How do I pass variable length arguments to parameters of another function?

```
def fun(a,b,c):
    #calculating
    pass

from inspect import signature

def example(*args):
    if len(args) >= len(signature(fun).parameters):
        fun(args); # how do i do this without modifying fun function
        return
    print("error")
```

Comment: well here you probably want to use `fun(*args[:3])`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slicing to make sure you have the right number of parameters, then use unpacking to pass them as individual arguments.

```
def example(*args):
    numargs = len(signature(fun).parameters)
    if len(args) >= numargs:
        return fun(*args[:numargs])
    print("not enough arguments")
```

Comment: So * is tuple unpacking operator?

Comment: It unpacks any sequence, not just tuples, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

Change `fun(args)` to `fun(*args[:3])`. This takes only the first 3 elements of `args` and unpacks them.

Edit: As kindall writes in his answer, you should also parameterise `numargs`.